# Any recommentadions of DAWs that can interact with external piano?

Tags: piano, midi, daw, midi-controller-keyboard

I must say that I don't even know how to explain my problem, but here I go. The thing is: I have an piano digital (yahama 36keys), but it's been a while since I got bored with reading sheets and just playing along. So, with a MIDI cable, I decided to donwload a simple DAW where I could play and actually see the notes/modify them if possible. Just like synthesia does, but recording. I'm afraid that if I just look for some software which does the recording, I won't be able to use the "styles" that came with the piano. 8 beat, jazz, flute, etc. Plus, it would be a pain to record with X, add some drums with Y, then finally mix them together with Z. There has to be something that does all of that...

Comment: I prefer trackers, and my favourite one is [Renoise](https://www.renoise.com/). But I have a background in chiptune, so it might not work for everyone. It's a bit more of a technical program, but they have a great community and their FAQ section is extremely extensive. Also, it's pretty damn cheap for an amazing DAW/tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Just about any standard DAW you get will do what you’re asking. Pretty much any software package you get will come bundled with a decent set of virtual instruments. I personally use Cubase which came with a decent virtual sound set, but Pro Tools, Ableton Live, and FL Studio are other common DAWs you might look into. You can get lite or basic versions of just about any of them too which would probably still include some of your virtual instrument sounds. Most of them should be pretty much plug-and-play with your keyboard too.

Comment: Since Cubase is the one I know, I can tell you that it has a fantastic MIDI editor tool where you can edit each individual MIDI note that you play (velocity, pitch, length, etc.). And I only have the Elements version of Cubase (the lite, cheaper version, not Pro) I would assume the others I mentioned have similar capabilities but I’m not as familiar with them.